# Dell Inspiron 5010 overheating issue ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dell, amd-graphics, overheating

I know this is a duplicate question. But none of the solutions provided for the previous questions worked for me. My laptop is shipped with a 1GB ATI graphics card. The laptop overheats even when it is idle. When I run Eclipse with ADT I can even prepare an Omelet on it. I have removed the Xorg driver and installed fglrx form ATI site but still the problem persists. Any solution will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions that may work for you, the first tried to get your Ati graphics card working instead of having both running at same time:

http://xpressrazor.wordpress.com/2013/01/13/how-to-setup-amdintel-hybrid-graphics-cards-in-linux-ubuntu/

... and the second disables Ati completely and lets you use the Intel chipset on it's own:

http://usernamepending.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/getting-back-some-battery-life-in-ubuntu-11-10-by-disabling-discrete-graphics/

... also, running the latest version of Ubuntu is recommended for newer drivers and support, Xubuntu if you would like a simpler non-3D desktop...

Answer (score 0):

update this bios
http://downloads.dell.com/bios/N5010A15.EXE

try cleaning up the vents, i have requested my friend at dell factory to check for any know issues in this model or solution for this issue.

Regards,
Mohan